# How to append SharedStringsTable while parsing XLSX to XML using DOM parser and Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, parsing, dom, apache-poi

My code is like this:

```
public class ReadXlsx {
public static void processDoc(String path)throws Exception
{
    OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(path); 
    XSSFReader r = new XSSFReader( pkg ); 
    SharedStringsTable sst = r.getSharedStringsTable();       
    DOMParser parser = new DOMParser(); 
    InputStream inp = r.getSheet("rId1"); 
    InputSource inpSource = new InputSource(inp); 
    inpSource.setEncoding("UTF-8");
    parser.parse(inpSource);


    Document doc = parser.getDocument(); 
    inp.close(); 

    OutputStream writer = new FileOutputStream(System.getProperty("user.home") + "//Desktop"+"//file.xml"); 
    TransformerFactory transfac = TransformerFactory.newInstance(); 
    Transformer trans = transfac.newTransformer(); 
                            trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes"); 
    trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes"); 
    trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8"); 

    //create string from xml tree 

    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer); 
    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc); 
    trans.transform(source, result); 
    XmlToJson.Convert(System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\Desktop"+"\\file.xml",System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\Desktop"+"\\Json4.json");
}}
```

The problem is when I convert .xlsx file to .xml file every strings in the sheet will be transformed to something like this

```
<c r="A1" s="43" t="s"><v>93</v></c>
```

That means the string in A1 is 94th string in sharedStrings.xml 
( t=s v=93 means the cell is a string array value is 93 )

I can get the SharedStringsTable but I have no idea how to include it in the
XML file so it will show the string instead of t=s v=93 like

```
<c r="A1" s="43"><t>This is String.</t></c>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use getEntryAt(int) function from the SharedStringsTable object as follows :

```
 SharedStringsTable sst = r1.getSharedStringsTable();//r1 being your XSSFReader
 CTRst st = sst.getEntryAt(k);//k is the index that you have in <v> tag
 st.getT();//getT() gets your value
```

The SharedStringsTable in its class is maintained as an ArrayList and a HashMap, both of them being private class members. The above snippet I wrote is accessing it from the ArrayList member. When you create SharedStringsTable object, entire SharedStrings xml is loaded as HashMap and ArrayList respectively.Therefore, streaming xlsx file does have this limitation. If there is a workaround, I'd like to know as we cannot override the private members(HashMap and ArrayList) of SharedStringsTable class.